# mysql join query should retrive result from 2 or 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables.
product table name:pc_products

```
id_product|id_merchant|product_name|product_category
123         flipkart     glass1          sunglass  
456         flipkart     glass2          sunglass
126         snapdeal     polo1           sunglass  
486         snapdeal     polo1           sunglass
```

primary key: id_merchant

merchant table name:pc_merchants

```
slug |  retailer
flipkart     Flipkart
snapdeal     Snapdeal
```

unique key:slug and foreign key for product table

discount table: discount

```
id|merchant| percentage|category_name
1  flipkart      5         sunglass
2  snapdeal      10        sunglass
```

Expected result: when i select any product as per that product's merchant and product's category, percentage should return.

tell me if any changes need to be done between table as foreign key.
the query i am using is:

```
select feed_product_name,id_merchant,category_name,percentage 
from pc_products_merchants m,pc_products p  
where m.slug = p.id_merchant and product_name LIKE '%glass1';
```

In this query i wanna retrieve percentage also of that product based on its retailer and category by using above 3 tables

Comment: you should use explicit joins and not implicit ones in your query

Comment: Can you please write the query for explicit join or implicit join. I don't have idea about that

Comment: This query is retrieving me same record twice with different percentage 5 and 10. that means retailer snapdeal with the value of 5 and 10. Where i just want to give the 10 percent discount for snapdeal retailer.

Comment: you should comment on my answer and not on your question... anyway see the updated version of the query. I have added the join condition on the merchant so that it will filter both on the category and the merchant looking for the discount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT pc_products.*, pc_merchants.retailer, discount.percentage
FROM pc_products 
JOIN pc_merchants ON pc_products.id_merchants = pc_merchants.slug 
JOIN discount ON pc_products.product_category = discount.category_name 
    AND pc_products.id_merchant = discount.merchant
WHERE product_name LIKE '%glass1'
```

This query use explicit joins. Implicit ones are no more used. Relations between the tables are declared in the FROM statement and WHERE is used only to filter the data

Comment: Thank you so much. This query is working fine.i appreciate your co-operation with me.